# Php Facebook - Upload Image from External Source

Tags: php, facebook, curl

Good morning fellows,
I am having an issue with facebook api:
is it possible to upload a photo from an external source? For instance, point out an URL and the Facebook will get that...
My code is right next 
`$args = array(
  'message' => 'Photo from application',
  'source' => $im_url
);`
`$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$album_id.'/photos?access_token='.$token;`
`$ch = curl_init();`
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);`
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);`
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);`
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);`
`$data = curl_exec($ch);`
the $im_url should point out to an external picture, like store on imageshack,etc.
The error it gives me is `{"error":{"message":"(#324) Requires upload file","type":"OAuthException"}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of "source", the term is "url". Problem solved
`$args = array(
  'message' => 'Photo from application',
  'url' => $im_url`

Comment: Thank you for this. I was looking at the documentation earlier and couldn't find it. I guess you have a sharper eye! -- It's still missing from the 'Fields' table, but it looks like it was hastily added to the end of the main description:

"You can also publish a photo by providing a url param with the photo's URL."

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/